# Issues with QuickCheck involving a data type with a function as a constructor

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

wrote the code below and am getting some issues with it :

The error I am getting is :     Data constructor not in scope: Int :: Int

If I eradicate the Numeric Int element from my array the code works perfectly fine, however Numeric Int is a constructor of the type Rank so it should also be included but I am unsure of how to include it without this error being produced.

Below is the code and apologises if this question is long-winded or silly, this is my first post on StackOverflow so any feedback on how this q was asked would also be greatly appreciated.

Any help would be immensely appreciated

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Data.Data
import Data.Typeable


data Suit = Spades | Hearts | Clubs | Diamonds
              deriving Show

data Colour = Black | Red
                deriving Show

colour :: Suit -> Colour
colour Spades = Black
colour Hearts = Red
colour Diamonds = Red
colour Clubs = Black

data Rank = Numeric Int | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
              deriving Show

rankBeats :: Rank -> Rank -> Bool
rankBeats _ Ace = False
rankBeats Ace _ = True
rankBeats _ King = False
rankBeats King _ = True
rankBeats _ Queen = False
rankBeats Queen _ = True
rankBeats _ Jack = False
rankBeats Jack _ = True
rankBeats (Numeric m) (Numeric n) = m > n

prop_rankBeats :: Rank -> Rank -> Bool
prop_rankBeats a b = rankBeats a b || rankBeats b a

instance Arbitrary Rank where
  arbitrary = elements [Numeric Int,Jack, Queen, King, Ace]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Arbitrary` instance for a `Rank` contains an `Int`:

```
instance Arbitrary Rank where
  --                      an Int ↓
  arbitrary = elements [Numeric Int, Jack, Queen, King, Ace]
```

But an `Int` is not a data constructor, but a type constructor. You can not use this.

What you can do is make a generator that looks like:

```
instance Arbitrary Rank where
  arbitrary = oneof ((Numeric <$> arbitrary) : map pure [Jack, Queen, King, Ace])
```

here the first item `Numeric <$> arbitrary` will use the `Arbitrary` instance of the `Int` type, and furthermore we use `map pure [Jack, Queen, King, Ace]` to transform these `Rank`s into `Gen Rank`s. The [**`oneof :: [Gen a] -> Gen a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:oneof) will then each time pick a random generator from the list. `oneof` will pick the items with equal weight. We can for example use `frequency` to pick these with different weights:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

instance Arbitrary Rank where
  arbitrary = frequency ((9, Numeric <$> chooseInt (2,10)) : map ((1,) . pure) [Jack, Queen, King, Ace])
```

here this is more fair: 9 out of 13 times, it will pick a `Numeric`, and we use `chooseInt (2, 10)` such that we only generate `Int`s between `2` and `10`.

Comment: Thank you so much. What does it mean to be an arbitrary instance though?

Comment: Also when you decided to add frequency, why did you do (1,). pure. What does that mean? Thanks once again

Comment: @harleengulati03: `pure` will transform a value `a` into a `Gen a`: a generator that will each time generate that value. `(1,)` wrap it in a 2-tuple with as first element `1`. This is the "weight" of the item, it determines how often it will generate a `Jack`/`Queen`/`King`/`Ace`. The `Numeric` one is thus generated nine times more often than a `Jack` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The code from Willem can also be generically derived.

Using the package [*generic-random*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-random-1.5.0.1/docs/Generic-Random-DerivingVia.html):

```
{-# Language DataKinds     #-}
{-# Language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# Language DerivingVia   #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Generic.Random.DerivingVia
import Test.QuickCheck

-- ghci> :set -XTypeApplications
-- ghci> sample @Rank arbitrary
-- King
-- Queen
-- King
-- Jack
-- Numeric (-4)
-- Numeric (-9)
-- Jack
-- Jack
-- Queen
-- Ace
-- Queen
data Rank = Numeric Int | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
  deriving
  stock (Show, Generic)

  deriving Arbitrary
  via GenericArbitraryU Rank
```

Adding weights (like `frequency`):

```
-- ghci> sample @Rank arbitrary
-- Numeric 0
-- Queen
-- Numeric (-4)
-- Numeric (-6)
-- Numeric 4
-- Numeric 3
-- Numeric 9
-- Numeric (-3)
-- Numeric 12
-- Jack
-- Numeric 20
data Rank = Numeric Int | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
  deriving
  stock (Show, Generic)

  deriving Arbitrary
  via GenericArbitrary '[9, 1, 1, 1, 1] Rank
```

We can even implement the `choose (2, 10)` with [*generic-override*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-override)!

```
{-# Language InstanceSigs             #-}
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables      #-}
{-# Language StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
{-# Language TypeApplications         #-}
{-# Language TypeOperators            #-}

..

import Data.Kind
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeLits
import System.Random

-- ghci> sample @Rank arbitrary
-- King
-- Numeric 10
-- Queen
-- Jack
-- Jack
-- King
-- Numeric 8
-- Numeric 7
-- Numeric 4
-- Numeric 4
-- Numeric 6
data Rank = Numeric Int | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
  deriving
  stock (Show, Generic)

  deriving Arbitrary
  via GenericArbitrary '[9, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        (Override Rank '[Int `With` Choose 2 10])
```

Using

```
type    Choose :: Nat -> Nat -> Type -> Type
newtype Choose n m a = Choose a

instance (KnownNat n, KnownNat m, Num a, Random a) => Arbitrary (Choose n m a) where
  arbitrary :: Gen (Choose n m a)
  arbitrary = Choose <$> choose (fromInteger (natVal @n Proxy), fromInteger (natVal @m Proxy))
```